# ReactJS state not updated In setState callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state, immutable.js

I'm currently building a SIP phone, where the current calls are handled by a SipPhone class, and displayed on the frontend using React. SipPhone has a list of calls which trigger callbacks that a React component is listening to.

The main phone component has an initial state containing an empty [Immutable List](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
    this.state = {
        calls: List(),
    };
}
```

This `calls` list is updated via an event triggered by callbacks whenever the SipPhone updates.

```
handleUpdate = ({ calls }) => {
    const nextCalls = List(calls.map(call => {
      return new Call({ ... }) // Call is an Immutable Record
    });

    console.log(nextCalls.toJS()); // This prints the new list I want to save
    this.setState({ calls: nextCalls }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.calls.toJS()); // The list is empty here
    });
}
```

Sometimes it successfully updates the `calls` list, while at other times `calls` doesn't change. When I log the list before setting state, it is as it should be, however when logging in the setState callback it remains unchanged from it's previous state. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

To further test this, I added a state variable `tick` which is incremented each time I set the state here. This change is accurately reflected in the callback, while the calls list remains unchanged.

I can't seem to figure out any reason why it would be doing this. I actually began this project using a normal array rather than an immutable list, and encountered the same issue. I've been using React for quite some time now and have never run into this problem...any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post a full code sample such as where the second code block is being called?

Comment: I've added a few more details -- unfortunately it's difficult to give full code samples in this case, as it is a fairly large project.

Comment: Never mind, I misunderstood in a hurry.

Comment: @RyanMcClure Hi..I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qq4y35qn/) based on your example and it's working fine. The only notable difference is that I've used `handleUpdate(calls)` instead of `handleUpdate = ({ calls })`. Can you take a look at it?  Are those curely braces necessary in parameter??

Comment: @RyanMcClure Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks Hardik, the curly braces are there because the arg being passed is an object and I'm just destructuring it there. Hmm, since it works fine in the fiddle, still not sure what might be causing the issue...

Comment: The thing is, the nextCalls list logs exactly as it should be before setting the state. I've even tried setting a global var to nextCalls at this point, logging it in the callback, and it accurately reflects the new list in that case but the state list still remains unchanged

Comment: Can you post your code as an example? If possible can you provide a fiddle that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out another function in my code was setting the state in certain cases right before componentWillUpdate is called, causing it to disregard the initial call to setState. This was the source of error.

Answer (score 0):

I personally found JsSIP library quite convoluted because of too many methods and nested callbacks. This is very different to what you normally work with in the React apps. My friend and I once created a simple component called `<SipProvider/>`, which abstracted all JsSIP complexity away and let us make calls by just configuring props and using context methods. We finally published that package on npm – feel free to benefit from it too!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sip

If you want to store some data in the apps's state but don't want to bother with redux / mobx / apollo client, a library called [`recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) may be helpful. It lets you lift the state into a higher-order component and thus separate the state logic from its representation. I've been using [`withState()`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withstate) / [`withReducer()`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#withreducer) in a few projects and it's difficult for me to imagine using `this.setState()` again!

Answer (score -1):

We'd faced this issue before , when we used Immutable (and not normal JS)

Digging around, came across this documentation snippet in react docs

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Unless using the callback function of `setState` is really mandated, i'd recommend going for `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: So from what I understand, the new state should always be reflected in the callback, because it is called after it has completed. However in my case, the new state is actually not updated at any point at all. Logging the list in the render function shows an unchanged list.